# What Android sync'd data is encrypted?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, sync, security, encryption, privacy

With the release of the [firesheep plug-in for firefox](http://codebutler.github.com/firesheep/) it has become trivial for website browsing on open Wi-Fi networks to be hijacked by 3rd party listeners.

Android offers the convenient auto-sync option. However I fear that my data may be auto-sync'd while I am connected to an open Wi-Fi network while at the local coffee shop or shopping mall.

Is all the data Android auto-syncs encrypted using SSL or a similar encryption mechanism? Is any auto-sync'd data unencrypted and transmitted in the clear for all to listen in to?

**Update**: COMPLETELY INSECURE!!!! See below!!!!

Comment: German Heise Magazine has a great article about that question. It's just in german, but you could use an Translation Service. link:[heise](http://www.heise.de/mobil/artikel/Sicherheit-von-Apps-fuer-Android-und-iPhone-1103681.html)

Comment: It seems, finally, Google will take care of its users data: http://www.uni-ulm.de/in/mi/mitarbeiter/koenings/catching-authtokens.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Note: answering my own question as nobody knew.

I did a packet capture after selecting Menu -> Accounts & Sync -> Auto-sync (also accessible via the "Power Control" widget). What did I discover?

To my *horror* (http requests from phone displayed below):

```
GET /proxy/calendar/feeds/myaccount%40gmail.com HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=_hidden_
Host: android.clients.google.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Android-GData-Calendar/1.4 (vision FRF91); gzip
```

and

```
GET /proxy/contacts/groups/myaccount@gmail.com/base2_property-android?showdeleted=true&orderby=lastmodified&updated-min=2010-12-01T08%3A49%3A00.561Z&sortorder=ascending&max-results=10000&requirealldeleted=true HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=_hidden_
GData-Version: 3.0
Host: android.clients.google.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Android-GData-Contacts/1.3 (vision FRF91); gzip
```

My *contacts* and *calendar* are being transmitted **unencrypted**! I don't currently synchronize gmail so I couldn't say if that is unencrypted either.

Also the stock market application (which must be a service because I don't have the widget displayed or the application active):

```
POST /dgw?imei=TEST&apptype=finance&src=HTC01 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.19.0 (i586-pc-mingw32msvc) libcurl/7.19.0 zlib/1.2.3
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 338
Host: api.htc.go.yahoo.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Expect: 100-Continue

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<request devtype="HTC_Model" deployver="HTCFinanceWidget 0.1" app="HTCFinanceWidget" appver="0.1.0" api="finance" apiver="1.0.1" acknotification="0000">
<query id="0" timestamp="0" type="getquotes">
<list><symbol>VOD.L</symbol><symbol>BARC.L</symbol></list></query>
</request>
```

*Completely* unencrypted request for stock quotes: just think, you could sit in Starbucks in the financial centre of your city and packet-sniff what quotes were important to all the smart phone users around you..

Other items that were not encrypted:

- http request to `htc.accuweather.com`
- [time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daytime_Protocol) request to `time-nw.nist.gov:13` (doesn't even use NTP)

About the *only* data that is encrypted on my phone are the mail accounts I set up with the K-9 application (because all my mail accounts use SSL - and fortunately gmail accounts are, by default, SSL; and [yahoo! mail supports imap using SSL](http://groups.yahoo.com/group/Y-Mail/message/19783) too). But it seems *none* of the auto-sync'd data from the out-of-box phone is encrypted.

This is on a [HTC Desire Z](http://www.htc.com/www/product/desirez/overview.html) with Froyo 2.2 installed. Lesson: *do not use phone on open wireless network without VPN encrypted tunnelling*!!!

Note, packet capture taken by using tshark on ppp0 interface on virtual node running Debian connected to Android phone via OpenSwan (IPSEC) xl2tpd (L2TP).

Comment: That's worrying. I can't see any cookies passing back and forward there, are they being sent in the clear too?

Comment: The `auth=` string contained what appeared to be similar to a cookie, I deleted it before posting here for security, however.

Comment: Is this still a current problem on Android 2.3.1?

Comment: I believe you can set up Android 4 to always use a VPN connection.

Answer (score 4):

Results captured on an LG Optimus V (VM670), Android 2.2.1, stock, rooted, purchased in March 2011.

As of today, the only unencrypted requests I could find in a pcap taken during a complete resync were:

### Picasa Web Albums

```
GET /data/feed/api/user/<username>?imgmax=1024&max-results=1000&thumbsize=144u,1024u
    &visibility=visible&kind=album HTTP/1.1
GData-Version: 2
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=<snipped>
If-None-Match: <snipped; don't know if it's sensitive info>
Host: picasaweb.google.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Cooliris-GData/1.0; gzip
```

### That's it.

Picasa was the only service I could find being synced unencrypted. Facebook requested a couple profile images (but didn't pass any account info); Skype requested ads; and TooYoou grabbed a new banner image. None of those relate to sync, really.

So it looks like Google's syncing security has been tightened quite a bit. **Turn off syncing Picasa Web Albums** and all of your Google data should be synced in encrypted form.

### Market

This bothered me a little:

```
GET /market/download/Download?userId=<snipped>&deviceId=<snipped>
    &downloadId=-4466427529916183822&assetId=2535581388071814327 HTTP/1.1
Cookie: MarketDA=<snipped>
Host: android.clients.google.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: AndroidDownloadManager
```

The return of this is a 302 Moved Temporarily that points to a highly complex download URL:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Cache-control: no-cache
Location: http://o-o.preferred.iad09g05.v5.lscache6.c.android.clients.google.com
          /market/GetBinary/com.wemobs.android.diskspace/1?expire=1322383029&ipbits=0
          &ip=0.0.0.0&sparams=expire,ipbits,ip,q:,oc:<snipped>
          &signature=<snipped>.<snipped>&key=am2
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 25 Nov 2011 08:37:09 GMT
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Android's download manager turns right around and requests that download location, passing the `MarketDA` cookie again.

I don't know if there's any security danger from how Market downloads APKs. The worst I can imagine is that unencrypted APK downloads open up the possibility of interception & replacement with a malicious package, but I'm sure Android has signature checks to prevent that.

Comment: I'm glad that since my initial discovery that others are taking this seriously now. Thank you! I felt I was alone in the wilderness when I posted the initial question/response. I've not actually done any retesting since the original post and kept to more secure practices - but I'm glad that others are following up on this.

Comment: I get funny looks from people sometimes because I spout off about security like it's normal. And three days after posting this, I snapped up a Cyber Monday deal on a new Motorola Triumph. Customer service issues delayed its arrival until last Wednesday, but I quickly discovered that it has major issues with EAP-secured networks. My college uses EAP. So I'm glad I looked into this. More may be coming, as I haven't yet tested Currents. ;)

Comment: I only want to encourage you - sound like a good person to care enough about security.